# Randomize query results sharing a certain property

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to run a query in Postgres that returns the result set as expected (say `SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY created_at DESC`), but shuffle the results a bit so that you don't have too many consecutive results that share the same `supplier_id` value.

This is especially important because products from each supplier tend to be imported at roughly the same time, making `created_at` the same, which means that several pages of results are often only 1 supplier's products.

How do you mix it up?

Comment: do you want only ONE of each supplier to show up in this shuffled data set, or duplicate suppliers are ok, as long as they're not "too frequent"?

Comment: Do you indent to order by **random**

Comment: Duplicates are ok, but not 'too frequent.' I just don't want more than X products with the same `supplier_id` to appear consecutively.

Comment: I.e., X > 1, So I assume I can't use `DISTINCT()`.

Answer (score 1):

If I finally understand your question right, the [window function `row_number()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) should do the job, with the right `PARTITION`:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY created_at, supplier_id
                                ORDER BY created_at DESC) AS rn
   FROM   products
   ) a
WHERE  rn <= X
ORDER  BY created_at DESC
```

The `ORDER BY` in the `OVER` clause is optional, but it speeds up execution in my tests with Postgres 9.1, because it syncs up with the final `ORDER BY` clause.

Up to `X` rows from the same supplier at the same time are selected arbitrarily. If you need truly random selection, you have to order by `random()` additionally in the `OVER` clause.

Other than that, this isn't "randomizing" or "reshuffling", but suppressing excess rows. If you want those rows (more than `X`) displayed, you'll have to define where in the sort order. It would inevitably break chronological order, though.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you want to sort results in chronological order, but for specific values of `created_at`, there is only one distinct value of `supplier_id` and you'd want to have several instead, assuming they're close enough in the sorted list.

The key problem would be that the resolution of `created_at`, whatever is it (`timestamp` has sub-second resolution, `timestamp(0)` would have a resolution of one second) is too high when used directly as the sort criterion.

You could try sorting by ranges of time instead. For example:

```
ORDER BY (extract(epoch from created_at)/3600)::int, RANDOM()
```

would order first by the hour (3600 secs) the entry was inserted, measured as the number of elapsed hours since 1/1/70, and then shuffle the results inside this range with the secondary sort (random). If the probability of having different suppliers inserted within the same hour is still too small, make it several hours or several days.